# Connect to MySQL database using Flask, SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to connect to **MySQL** database using Flask. Below is my code:

```
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'admin'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = '********'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'abc'

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://admin:********@localhost/abc'

api = Api(app)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
ma = Marshmallow(app)

db.create_all()

class Video(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    videoid = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    video_timestamp = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=True)

    def __init__(self, videoid, video_timestamp):
        self.videoid = videoid
        self.video_timestamp = video_timestamp
```

and I met this error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pymysql.err.ProgrammingError) (1146,
>   "Table 'abc.video' doesn't exist") [SQL: 'SELECT video.id AS
>   video_id, video.videoid AS video_videoid, video.video_timestamp AS
>   video_video_timestamp \nFROM video']

I know how to connect to **SQLite** database, but it seems difficult to connect to **MySQL** database?

Anyone can help me, please?

Comment: not 100% sure, could it be that you call `db.create_all()` before the `Video` model is declared?

Comment: I try to remove this line and in **terminal** I try to open python3 and use the following code:

    ```from my_app import db```

but it doesn't work

Comment: How exactly isn't it working?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a problem to connect to your database but it looks like your table are not created yet.
so remove the  `db.create_all()` in your code and check this from [the sql_alchemy official documentation](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/quickstart/#a-minimal-application) :

> To create the initial database, just import the db object from an
>   interactive Python shell and run the SQLAlchemy.create_all() method to
>   create the tables and database:

```
from yourapplication import db
db.create_all()
```

Comment: I tried but the same error occurs. I know this way to create tables manually.

Comment: After removing the db.create_all() in your code you run the and run it in python console it refuse?

Comment: @detuvoldo I've added those infos but I'm unable to reproduce your error

Comment: No, I have not. I am trying to connect to **MariaDB**

Answer (score 0):

The code to connect to Mysql:

```
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
```

cursorclass, and autocommit to make life easier

```
mysql = MySQL(autocommit=True, cursorclass= DictCursor)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'Thisissupposedtobesecret!'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'db'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PORT'] = 8889
app.config['MYSQL_CURSORCLASS'] = 'DictCursor'
mysql.init_app(app)

connect cursor 
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

You can download xxamp or Mamp and host database online at phpmyadmin (localhost)

Comment: I'm trying to use ORM :D
Thanks for your help

Comment: Autocommit very much makes life a pain.

Comment: Even for small projects?